# Print out list of non-uniform parameters in C

Tags: c, embedded

I have some device with lot of different parameters, which could be bool, char, int, float, string and so on. I need to print them all at once in some AJAX array (for the web interface control). I have to use pure C, and also this code will be run on some MCU with narrow ROM/RAM resources.  What is the possible ways to do it? If they there all uniform, like int’s, I could just use array:

```
Uint16_t params[PARAM_1]=GetParam(PARAM_1);

PrintParams(&params)
{
   For(iii=0;iii<MAX_COUNT;iii++)
   {
   HTTPPrint(params[iii]);
   }
}
```

But they are not. 
Not grouping them at all will be prone to errors then adding/removing parameters, and also overhead:

```
Uint16_t param1= GetParam1();
Float param2= GetParam2();

PrintParams(&params)
{
HTTPPrint(param1);
HTTPPrint(param2);
//another 100+ parameters to print

}
```

Using some advanced data structure, like linked list will be huge overhead (for any singe char need to store 4-byte pointer at least).
Maybe there is another ways to do it?

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using a struct?

Comment: If you don't get the type of the variable from the context, you could implement a variant type with a struct that holds a flag for the type and a union for the data. This will have an overhead of the flag, probably an ´int`. (Making the flag a `char` won't help, because of struct padding.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tagged union allows you to carry type information with the data and doesn't take a lot of space:

```
enum type_t {
    kTypeChar = 1,
    kTypeInt = 2
};

union data_t { 
    char i8; 
    int i32; 
};

struct anytype { 
    enum type_t tag; 
    union data_t data;
};
```

You can directly do case-analysis on stored value type. Although it does leave some room for error in mismatching type tag and value:

```
struct anytype v = GetParam(PARAM_1);

switch (v->tag) {
case kTypeChar: HTTPPrintChar(v->data.i8); break;
case kTypeInt:  HTTPPrintInt(v->data.i32); break;
default:        assert(0);
};
```

Or you can add a polymorphic print handler into each type to make it less error prone. Although it will consume additional space to carry a pointer with all data items but it is kinda less prone to error and easier to use.

```
typedef void (*print_func_t) (struct polytype* self);

struct polytype {
    print_func_t print;
    union data_t data;
};

void print_char(struct polytype* self) {
    HTTPPrintChar(self->data.i8);
}

void print_int(struct polytype* self) {
    HTTPPrintChar(self->data.i32);
}

struct polytype t = GetParam(PARAM_1); /* GetParam sets proper print fptr based on param type */
t.print(&t);
```